# Integer values of $n$ when $n^3+1$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

If $n^3+1$ is a perfect square, find all integer values of $n$.
I have proved that when n³+1 is even then the only solution for n is $-1$. However, I am not so confident for my solution in the case of $n^3+1$ being odd. I would appreciate answers solving this specific case.
The solutions are $-1,0,2$.

Note: I am aware that this question has been asked already however the solution makes use of elliptic curves and I would prefer a quite elementary and simple solution.

Comment: Context for this question?

Comment: Writing $n^3=(m-1)(m+1)$ we see that both $m\pm 1$ must be perfect cubes (possibly ignoring powers of $2$).

Comment: @Mike I found this on a video online on math Olympiad problems. They did not provide the solution.

Comment: @lulu Yes but I want to prove that if n³ is even then the only values for n are 0,2.